# What is the Last Digit in the Result of the given Expression?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

$Given$:

$ASC$ is a concatenated number with distinct digits.

$S$ is square of $A$, $C$ is cube of $A$

Deduce the last digit of the following Expression through Deductive Reasoning only:

$$\begin{align}A^S&\times A^{ASC}\\ +\space S^C&\times S^{ASC}\\ +\,C^A&\times C^{ASC}\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm VTC because determining A, S, C is completely trivial, and this reduces to a very routine number theory problem, so this is not a puzzle.

Comment: (I'm also inclined to close as not-a-puzzle on different grounds: that this is something to *recognize* more than something to actually *solve*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As A, S, C are single digit numbers, $A=2,S=4,C=8$.
>  So we have $$2^4 2^{248} + 4^8 4^{248} + 8^2 8^{248} =4^{126} + 4^{256} + 4^{375} \equiv 6+6+4 \equiv 6$$.

Reason

> Odd power of $4 \equiv 4$ (last digit)  and
>  Even power of $4\equiv6$ (last digit)